# How to fake Alamofire request for unit testing?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, networking, mocking, alamofire

In my app, I'm using Alamofire to make network calls, but now, I want to test the calls.

I do the network call like this :

```
AF.request(myURL).responseData { response in 
    // Decode the data
    // Translate the data into an object
}
```

I tried to fake the AF session and override his request, but I don't know what should go inside.

```
class FakeAFSession: Session {
    override func request(_ convertible: URLRequestConvertible, interceptor: RequestInterceptor? = nil) -> DataRequest {
        // Fake the network request here
    }
}
```

Here is how I want the test to run.

```
func testGivenCallbackFailed_WhenErrorInNetworkCall_ThenObjectReturnAreNil(){
        // MARK: - Given
        
        // I want to create a fake request
        let fakeRequest = FakeNetworkRequest()
        
        // I want to pass the request to the fake session of Alamofire
        let fakeSession = FakeAFSession(request: fakeRequest)
        
        // Finally, I want to pass the session to the service
        let service = RecipeService(session: fakeSession)
        
        // MARK: - When
        let expectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "Error in network call")
        
        let fakeIngredients = ["Mozzarella", "Tomato"]
        service.getRecipe(containing: fakeIngredients) { _recipes, success, _error in
            // MARK: - Then
            // Here is where I should test the network call
            
            XCTAssertNil(_recipes)
            XCTAssertFalse(success)
            XCTAssertNotNil(_error)
            
        }
        wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 0.01)
    }
```

What technique should I use if this one is not recommended or the best ?

**PS :** I don't want to use only Xcode expectations to wait for the response,I really want to use faking or mocking process.

Thank's in advance for your answers.

Comment: How do you plan to write the unit tests?

Comment: I plan to use the BDD way of writing tests. I plan to create a fake session, pass it fake data ( correct and incorrect ) and test the outcome.

Comment: OK, but how would such a unit test look like? What do you plan to actually mock/fake? Can you show us some code, even if not compiling?

Comment: Sure, I've just updated the question !

Comment: Check this article, it might help: https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/mocking-alamofire-urlsession-requests/